# How can I add different custom fields for each category in the same post?

Tags: categories, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to add different custom fee fields for each selected category in the same post/course. Here is an example:-

Course Name: B.tech
Categories/colleges: college 1, college 2, college 3, college 4

If multiple colleges assign to the same course, who can I differentiate fees with custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Advanced Custom Fields Plugins for different custom fee fields for each selected category in the same post.
You can download free acf plugin for wordpress.org

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried with acf but there is no such option which I am looking for.  I have done it in another way.